# Why checkboxes are not selected?

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkAll(formname, checktoggle)
{
    var checkboxes = new Array();
    checkboxes = document.forms[formname].getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox")   {
            checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor='lightgray'>
    <a onclick="javascript:checkAll('myform',true);" href="#">check all</a>
<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo "<form name='myform'>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' id='chk' name='chk' /> $rows[subject]";
        echo "</form>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It may not answer the question, but all your checkboxes share the same ID.

Comment: can you add generated html in your question and also make sure you have different name and for each checkbox

Comment: The problem is that u make multiple forms with the name `myform` and in your javascript you're only accounting for one form

Comment: You don't need "javascript:" at the front of the value for an "onclick" attribute.

Comment: Your question should have some text describing the the issue and your question. There are some smart people here on SO, but no mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php

    echo "<form name='myform'>";
    $n = 1;
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

        echo "<input type='checkbox' id='chk" . $n++  . "' name='chk' /> $rows[subject]";

    }
    echo "</form>";

?>
```

put the `<form>....</form>` outside the loop, otherwise you get numerous forms with the name "myform" which then is not handled properly in your javascript, see comment from [DarkBee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446594/darkbee)

Comment: working now. Thanx a lot DarkBee.

Comment: Yw. Thx to Axel for making it into an answer :)